# Was Stack Overflow just down and out?

Tags: feature-request, support

Was stackoverflow, stackexchange, etc just down and out for the past 30 mins?

I also tried to see the status on http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com and it confirmed that you guys were down for them too.

Feature-Request: Can there be a status ticker somewhere? or a heartbeat system like twitter has? Or like [@tichodroma](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177964/tichodroma) [points out](http://status.fastmail.fm/) [`the FastMail quys`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155041/was-stack-overflow-just-down-and-out-for-the-past-30-mins#comment445295_155042)

---

[What if I can't open a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155093/what-if-i-cant-open-a-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: +1 "Is there a status ticker somewhere? or a heartbeat system like twitter has?"

Comment: @Tichodroma yes - it's called "the users" who refresh the home page every couple of seconds.

Comment: +1 Experienced same. Was going to post same and saw your question.

Comment: @Tichodroma there is now [StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a ploy to make me go back to doing my work. Both the site being down, and it's extreme slowness right now :)

Comment: @Rachel - unsurprisingly, THAT was the part that freaked me out!! an i now also need a new keyboard with a working `F5` key ;)

Comment: I've been noticing that SO was going down a bit yesterday, and it just happened again a few minutes ago.

Comment: It just happened again.

Comment: @Luke - yes, it did.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stack Exchange was experiencing routing issues, from [Nick Craver](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/266525435876220928)'s twitter feed:

> Nick_Craver: Our upstream provider was doing a OS upgrade on their core router, the switch to the backup caused the blip #stackoverflow #stackexchange

I generally check [his feed](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver) when there are issues, as well as the [ServerFault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/). I am not aware of a separate, dedicated status page for the network anywhere.

Edit: As [just announced via Twitter](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/266537461717553154) there is now a dedicated Twitter account, a status page and access to the Pingdom status has been opened up:

- https://twitter.com/StackStatus
- https://www.stackstatus.net/
- http://stats.pingdom.com/w2oc4thvox7s

Comment: The last blog update is from October 31st, 2012. That's not what I would call a status ticker :)

Comment: @Tichodroma: But major (planned) upgrades *are* being discussed there.

Comment: True. But I'd like to see something like [the FastMail quys have](http://status.fastmail.fm/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yes, it's a great place to check up on planned events. If I am not mistaken, in the current blip, the whole `Stack` stack was down. Which is where the twitter posts you pointed out from Nick come into the picture. :)

Comment: I quite agree it's a great idea to have a status page, but there isn't one available now, and I am not in a position to make that happen. :-) Just trying to help out by showing where I get my information from right now, without such a page.

Comment: +1 honestly, thanks for the Nick link. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters there is a new way to monitor StackExchange status on twitter -- [StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus)

Comment: @bluefeet: Yup, found it as well. :-)