# What if I can't open a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, faq-proposed, offline

If I can't get to any of the Stack Exchange sites, where do I look to get a status update?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: I have flagged it already. waiting for a mod to action it.

Comment: If I can't get to any of the Stack Exchange sites, how am I reading this question?  ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson - ;) first rule of any forum, *read the faq*. So by the time the site goes down, you already knew! :) AND... Google's cached it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although highly unlikely that the whole of the Stack Exchange Network should get [affected](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/35274839341/outage-nov-8th-2012-update), the following web locations should enable users to gain more insight into the status:

- [StackStatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/)
- [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus)

Status can also be checked on these automatic tools:

- http://stats.pingdom.com/w2oc4thvox7s
- http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/stackexchange.com